# Color View not visible when placed within NavigationLink

Tags: swiftui-navigationlink

I wonder why can't I see my blue buttons between the Images when running this code?

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            ForEach(self.sets) { set in
                NavigationLink(destination: DeferView { ExerciseVideoView(items: set.items).navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true) }) {
                    VStack {
                        Image("group-\(set.image)")
                            .resizable()
                            .renderingMode(.original)
                            .frame(height: 200, alignment: .leading)
                            .overlay(
                                Text(set.purpose)
                                    .font(.largeTitle)
                                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                        )
                        Color.blue
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .overlay(
                                Text(set.purpose)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I only see the images but Color.blue is hidden for some reason. **Everything works fine without NavigationLink**.

Is something wrong with rendering template?

Please advise